# java driver in selenium project

Tags: java, forms, selenium

I am using simple project, where you fill in the form. The last part is to click on a element with no id and no text.

I found that i could use java to do it, but how do i initiate the driver in selenium?

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(knownElement, 10, 25).click().build().perform();
```

I tried

```
WebDriver driver = New ChromeDriver();
```

but that only raised a lot new problems. I am using IntelliJ.

Comment: What are the _lot new problems_ you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need chromedriver.exe to initiate selenium web driver.

First download the ChromeDriver. You need to download ChromeDriver for your respective Operating system from this [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

```
    //Then set the download location. 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium-java//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
    //Creating an object of ChromeDriver
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   //launching the specified URL
   driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Then find your element to be clicked using xpath.

If you say you don't have any id or text for click then use any parent element as reference which you can identify then use xpath axes to identify it.

Then you can click on that element directly.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id = 'id']/child::button")).click;
```